# Fast algorithm to recognize sortable sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, computational-complexity

Every sequence is sortable in the worst-case by a $O(n^2)$. However, if we restrict sorting primitive, we get an interesting problem. I am interested in this sorting problem:

**Input**: a sequence $A$ of $2N$ positive integers.

**Question**: Is it possible to sort sequence $A$ using only $N$ transpositions?

Each transposition swaps two non-adjacent elements $a_i$ and $a_j$ in $A$ (two elements are not adjacent if $|i−j|>1$). My intuition is that the problem should be $NP$-complete.

> Is this problem $NP$-complete? Is it polynomial-time decidable?

One such sequence: A=$[7,5, 9, 10, 2, 8, 1, 6, 3, 4]$. Swap pairs (4,10), (7,1),(8,6), (3,9), and (2,5).

In general, numbers in the sorted sequence are not nesseraily consecutive.

Comment: The answer is simply "no" to the first Question, so all the other questions are vacuous. You can't sort 4, 3, 2, 1 in just two transpositions (where you don't swap adjacent elements). Since the only "first" transposition that can put TWO elements in the right place is (1,4) - and this leaves (2,3) for the second move, which is illegal - this means that the "first" transposition can move no more than one element to the right place, which leaves three elements out of place and only one move left.

Comment: @mathguy That is not a question. The input-question pair defines what is known as _Computational Problem_

Comment: @mathguy This question asks whether "given an array of $2N$ numbers, tell me if I can sort it with at most $N$ transposition" is decidable in a polynomial time.

Comment: See http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/4098/381

Comment: Oh, I got it. There I was, thinking I can decide it in no time at all!   :-)

Comment: If the sequence contains no duplicate elements, then one can determine the smallest number of swaps necessary by first sorting and annotating each element with its index in the sorted sequence; the number of swaps is $2N$ minus the number of cycles in the permutation defined by the function that takes an index to the index its element is annotated with.  This is clearly doable in polynomial time.  With duplicates, things seem to get tricky.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon Not sure that I get your algorithm. Does your efficient algorithm work for $A=[20, 3, 10, 4, 1 , 13, 7, 17]$?

Comment: This defines the permutation $(8,2,5,3,1,6,4,7)$ or in cycle notation $(1,8,7,4,3,5)(2)(6)$, so at least $8-3 = 5$ swaps are necessary.  However, I notice now that you disallow non-adjacent elements in a swap, so the formula I suggested (also mentioned in an answer referenced in another comment) has to be modified.  I'm not sure disallowing adjacent elements in swaps is natural.  The interesting case still seems to be when there are duplicates in the sequence, since this forces choice which may allow a reduction of a known hard problem to this one.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon Swapping non-adjacent elements is OK. I disallow swapping two adjacent elements.